# Warning: returning reference to temporary - strange case (Clarification for Rvalue)

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, rvalue, temporary

In this code:

```
const int & fun(const int &i)
{
    return 2*i;
}

int main()
{
    const int k=3;
    cout<<fun(k)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case the parameters of `fun` are not local (No **Temporary** object made to store the *Reference* return type) then why this warning?
**+** If I remove **const** from the return type of **function fun** it says

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’

But on removing **2*** (only **i** left as value being returned) it doesn't show any error -> What I can think is this **2*** thing is converting the return into **Rvalue** but then isn't the return value an **Rvalue** itself? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `2*i` results in a temporary. You then return a reference to that temporary. Kaboom!

Comment: Note that using the returned value is undefined even if you keep the `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return 2*i;` does not multiply `2` by `i` and store that result into `i`.  It multiples `2` by `i` and puts that result into a temporary.  Trying to return that temporary by reference is a no go as it is destroyed at the end of that line.  lifetime extension does not apply here.

If you want to modify `i` and return it you need to use `operator *=` which will modify `i` and give you a reference to it that you can return like

```
return i *= 2;
```

But `fun` would need to take a `int&` instead of `const int &`.

---

If you want to return an rvalue then what you do is return by value like:

```
int fun(const int &i)
{
    return 2*i;
}
```

and now you can capture it like:

```
int main()
{
    const int& ret = fun(3);
    cout << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```